# Apache Beam + Databricks Notebook - map function error

Tags: databricks, apache-beam

I am trying to run a simple pipeline using Apache Beam on DataBricks Notebooks, but I am unable to create any custom functions. Here is a simple example:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

def my_func(s):
    print(s)

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions([
    "--runner=DirectRunner",
])

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    (
    p
    | "Create data" >> beam.Create(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
    | "print result" >> beam.Map(my_func)
    )
```

Produces:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to pickle fn CallableWrapperDoFn(<function Map.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fb5a17a6b80>): It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

This error also occurs if I use a `lambda` function. Everything works as expected if I use the builtin `print` function. Why am I getting this error? How can I pass custom functions to my pipeline in this environment?

Answer (score 0):

Reference to `SparkContext` seems to be getting pulled in when the lambda function gets serialized by Beam.

Instead of using `beam.Map` can you try defining a new Beam `DoFn` and using the [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) transform ?

Comment: Good thought, but it results in a variation of the same error

Comment: I'm not sure then. This might be an issue related to Notebooks support. Feel free to file a Github issue against the Apache Beam team: https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/